# Docker process exiting when prisma client tries to connect to aurora db

Tags: amazon-web-services, prisma, aws-fargate, amazon-aurora

I've got a nestjs application running in docker on AWS (using fargate) that I want to connect to an aurora database using prisma.

Currently I can run database migrations (from another fargate task), but whenever my application tries to do anything in the database the process exits. Nothing is showing up in the logs - the container process just exits, and I can't even find an exit code.

The system works locally, and the applications runs fine on AWS until it tries to reach the database. It also works if I swap out the aurora db for a rds instance.

The database is set up to allow incoming connections from both the application service security group and the security group used for the migrations task (in the same way).

Any ideas on how I can fix this, or at least debug the issue?

Comment: Try enabling Prisma debugging to see if you get any meaningful logging from that - https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/debugging

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I was able to fix this in my Dockerfile  by going from node:20-alpine3.16 to node:20-alpine3.18

Source: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10649